# Proving $\frac{a}{b^3}+\frac{b}{c^3}+\frac{c}{a^3}\geqslant \frac{a+b}{b^3+c^3}+\frac{b+c}{c^3+a^3}+\frac{c+a}{a^3+b^3}$

Tags: inequality, sum-of-squares-method, uvw, cyclic-decomposition

For $a,b,c>0.$ Prove$:$ $$\dfrac{a}{b^3}+\dfrac{b}{c^3}+\dfrac{c}{a^3}\geqslant \dfrac{a+b}{b^3+c^3}+\dfrac{b+c}{c^3+a^3}+\dfrac{c+a}{a^3+b^3}\quad (\text{Tran Quoc Thinh}) $$

It's easy with Buffalo Way and computer so I will not post it.

(*Please don't post solution by Buffalo Way, thanks for a real a lot!*)

So$,$ we try to find a solution by hand.

I get this SOS$:$

$$\sum {\dfrac { \left( 6\,{a}^{5}+5\,{a}^{4}b+2\,{a}^{4}c+4\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}+4
\,{a}^{3}bc+8\,{a}^{2}{b}^{3}+6\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}c+3\,a{b}^{4}+4\,a{b}^{
3}c-2\,{b}^{5}+2\,{b}^{4}c \right)  \left( a-b \right) ^{2}}{{a}^{3}{b
}^{3} \left( a+b \right)  \left( {a}^{2}-ab+{b}^{2} \right) }} \geqslant 0,$$

By SOS theorem$,$ if $$S_a+S_b+S_c \geqslant 0 ; S_a S_b +S_b S_c +S_cS_a\geqslant 0.$$

Then $$S_a (b-c)^2 +S_b (c-a)^2 +S_c(a-b)^2\geqslant 0.$$

Here$,$ we can prove$:$ $$S_a+S_b+S_c \geqslant 0,$$

but $$S_a S_b +S_b S_c +S_cS_a\geqslant 0$$ is not true!

pqr or $uvw$ technique give a very high degree, I think it is impossble.

Comment: What about abc or xyz? 

Comment: The pqr expression is complicated.

Comment: @MartinR I don't know it.

Comment: @RiverLi yes it's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^{10}c^6+a^9b^7-a^7b^6c^3-a^6b^6c^4)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM:

$$\sum_{cyc}a^{10}c^6=\frac{1}{38}\sum_{cyc}\left(14a^{10}c^6+21b^{10}a^6+3c^{10}b^6\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[38]{a^{14\cdot10+21\cdot6}b^{21\cdot10+3\cdot6}c^{16\cdot6+3\cdot10}}=\sum_{cyc}a^7b^6c^3$$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}a^9b^7=\frac{1}{67}\sum_{cyc}\left(33a^9b^7+19b^9c^7+15c^9a^7\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[67]{a^{33\cdot9+15\cdot7}b^{33\cdot7+19\cdot9}c^{19\cdot7+15\cdot9}}=\sum_{cyc}a^6b^6c^4$$ and we are done!

Comment: +1), Very nice, which idea to find this$?$

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer :

I rewrite the inequality like this with $a\geq c \geq b>0$:

$$\dfrac{a}{b^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{c^3}{b^3}+1}\Big)+\dfrac{b}{c^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{a^3}{c^3}+1}\Big)+\dfrac{c}{a^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{b^3}{a^3}+1}\Big)\geq-\Big(\dfrac{b}{c^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{b^3}{c^3}+1}\Big)+\dfrac{c}{a^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{c^3}{a^3}+1}\Big)+\dfrac{a}{b^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{a^3}{b^3}+1}\Big)\Big)$$

Or :
$$\dfrac{a}{b^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{c^3}{b^3}+1}\Big)+\dfrac{b}{c^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{a^3}{c^3}+1}\Big)+\dfrac{c}{a^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{b^3}{a^3}+1}\Big)\geq\Big(\dfrac{b}{c^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{c^3}{b^3}+1}\Big)+\dfrac{c}{a^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{a^3}{c^3}+1}\Big)+\dfrac{a}{b^3}\Big(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\frac{b^3}{a^3}+1}\Big)\Big)$$

Now use rearrangement inequality with the constraint $\frac{c}{b}\geq \frac{a}{c}\geq \frac{b}{a}$ and $\frac{a}{b^3}\geq \frac{b}{c^3}\geq \frac{c}{a^3}$

Comment: @tthnew what do you think about my partial answer ?

Comment: I don't know much about rearrangement. I think Rearrangement is not enough strong. I will read your partial answer soon. Now I'm busy, sorry.

Comment: @c-love-garlic Both your last inequalities are wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg you speak about $\frac{c}{b}\geq \frac{a}{c}\geq \frac{b}{a}$ and $\frac{a}{b^3}\geq \frac{b}{c^3}\geq \frac{c}{a^3}$  ? If yes it's a constraint try $a=0.4$ $b=0.25$ and $c=0.35$ .

Comment: @c-love-garlic But it's wrong for any $a\geq c\geq b>0$. Also, can you explain, why did you post your "partial solution", if there is a right solution already?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I don't think so try my example .

Comment: @c-love-garlic Try $(a,b,c)=(5,1,2)$. For this numbers your first inequality is wrong. What do you think now?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg be clear if you speak about the constraint it don't cover all the numbers that's why I said it's partial .

Comment: @c-love-garlic You said that $a\geq c\geq b$ and $5\geq2\geq1$, which says that your "partial" reasoning is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes, now I see that more clearly wrong, as I say in past is Rearrangement is not strong enough.

Comment: @RiverLi Do you think it's wrong ?